# structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj")

Tags: r, object

I'm tring to use the `soilphysics` package and the `fitsoilwater` funciton.
It works pretty well with simple data sets but fails when I try to use bigger data sets with thousands of records (which is not usual I agree).

this is the error I get, poorly understandable for a beginner

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] floating point value is Not a Number.
```

so this works well,

```
ref_h<-c(1,10,22,60,100,200,300,600)
ref_VWC<-c(0.40838,0.3823,0.36928,0.35342,0.3394,0.25122,0.21506,0.1787)
fitsoilwater(ref_VWC, ref_h)
```

the same principle with longer vectors doesn't work and gives the error I mentionned.

Any comment welcome

Comment: Can you give an example where the error occurs?

Comment: How many is too many? It works for me with 10,000 (random) points. At least, the graph and the widgets appear, and I can adjust the red line with the sliders. At what point does it fail for you?

Comment: I tried to extract the first data of my dataset to show it to you. Up to 4000 records, it works! Above that, the error appears.  I think I could subsample my data set. But I'd like to understand the error.

Comment: Perhaps it's something about record 4001 in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an NA in `ref_VWC`:

```
> ref_h<-c(1,10,22,60,100,200,300,600)
> ref_VWC<-c(0.40838,0.3823,0.36928,0.35342,0.3394,0.25122,0.21506,0.1787)
> fitsoilwater(ref_VWC, ref_h)
```

works fine, but then:

```
> ref_VWC[4]=NA
> fitsoilwater(ref_VWC, ref_h)
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] floating point value is Not a Number.
```